# Post request to server not properly working Volley

Tags: android, post, android-volley

Hi guys i am facing a problem and the problem is that i am trying to send post request to server and i am getting exception

**com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of**

when i try to send data through get request it is working properly and when i try to send data through post request i am getting the above exception i have tried searching but not succeeded.
below is my code

```
 JsonObjectRequest _send_cab_data_to_server = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            cab_Data_Url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e("", "response : " + response);

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("", "error : " + error.toString());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Method", "CarLocation");
            params.put("data", _Cab_Locations_In_Driver_Service);
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    Volley_Controller.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(_send_cab_data_to_server,
            "volley");


}
```

and the data attribute corresponds to a set of strings that are combined
e.g **Ï2|33.7129221|73.0634634|Apr28,201510:50:33AM|0ÎÏ2|33.7129272|73.0634653|Apr28,201510:50:58AM|0Î**

and the json response is

{
"Success": true,
"Info": "Successful",
"Response": [
{
"Status": "Done"
}
]
}

Comment: Post that example JSON response. Also post the logcat output.

Comment: Up vote the answer too if it has helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i try to send data through get request it is working properly and
>   when i try to send data through post request i am getting the above
>   exception

As you said you are getting below exception:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

This means that you are getting `null` response. You are supposed to use GET method only, not the POST method because your server is not responding to the post request but rather returning a null object and so your parser is getting failed at parsing null object.

FYI, There is a meaning and importance of GET and POST method. Use the appropriate method defined by your server API.